# WooCommerce Display Multiple Taxes in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have 2 products in the site 1 one has 7% "Reduced Tax" and 1 has 19% Standard Tax. But when a user adds both of the products in the cart it display's only 19% tax in there. However, it's applying perfectly.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about software settings (tax settings) and doesn't involve coding.

Comment: Can you let me know where it? I can't see any settings for that?

Comment: The last tax setting **"Display tax totals" => *"Itemized"*** *(work with exluding tax display on cart/checkout)*

Comment: Yes, I have checked this as well it show's like this : http://prntscr.com/kndg9k

Comment: See [**this screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIVAm.png) … So as you can see it works and it's about settings.

Comment: Can you let me know what's the hook/template that it comes from?

Comment: Nothing special, just default templates (using storefront theme without any customizations).